# What happens if I dont specify the size and base format for unknown state?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, hdl

What happens if I do something like

> Signal1 = 'x;

as opposed to something like

> Signal1 = 4'bxxxx;

Are there any differences? Note that I have previously declared `Signal1` as

> reg[3:0] Signal1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This difference is if/when you change the width of `Signal1` to be more than 4 bits and forget to change `4'bxxxx`, you are going to silently get 0 padding. `'x`, `'z`, `'0`, and `'0` are all *fill literals* that expand to width of whatever context they are in.

This is only applicable to SystemVerilog, not Verilog.